# Fetching the IP address on OS X Mojave

Tags: osx, ip-address

I used this command to fetch the IP address of my workstation (running OS X 10.14.5 
) in a script, but I am wondering if somebody out there/OS X has a better solution.

```
ifconfig en0 | grep netmask | cut -d" " -f2
```

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20547/how-do-i-find-my-ip-address-from-the-command-line

Comment: On the mark! brilliant!!